# pandas resample - issue with epoch and frequency

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample, resample

I'd like to get a time series with a fixed set of dates in the index. I thought that `resample` with `freq` and `epoch='origin'` will do the trick. It seems that I'm using this method in a wrong way. Here's an example that shows that `epoch='origin'` does not seem to work.

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', freq="1D")
freq = '2W-MON'
vals = range(len(dates))
print(
pd.Series(vals,index = dates)
    .resample(freq, 
              origin="epoch",
              convention='end')
    .sum()
    .to_markdown()
)
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022-01-17 00:00:00 | 133 |
| 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 329 |
| 2022-02-14 00:00:00 | 31 |

If I change the first date in the series to anything after the "2022-01-03", I get a different result.

```py
dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-04', '2022-02-01', freq="1D")
freq = '2W-MON'
vals = range(len(dates))
print(
pd.Series(vals,index = dates)
    .resample(freq, 
              origin="epoch",
              convention='end')
    .sum()
    .to_markdown()
)
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 21 |
| 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 189 |
| 2022-02-07 00:00:00 | 196 |

I'd expect that if the `freq='2W-MON'` and `epoch='origin'`, both the examples will end up with the same dates (so, both should have either 2022-01-10 or 2022-01-03).

Is there an elegant way of forcing pandas to actually use `epoch="origin"`?

Comment: indeed, it seems using this frequency (or other multiple week frequencies) does not work as you expect with origin set. A work around is to pick a random Monday, use 14D s frequency and then if really needed change the frequency to 2W-MON, then use as_freq. so something like `pd.Series(vals,index = dates).resample('14D', origin='2022-01-03').sum().asfreq('2W-MON')` gives the behavior I understand you are expecting!

Comment: Yup, this one works. Thank you!